Hreflang issue wvwn when my site doen't have multiple languages
My site doesn't have any other version in any other language except for English.
Still in my SEMrush its showing HREFLANG issue.

I checked online on how to solve this, and added the below on my homepage :
Still didn't solve the issue.
I repeat, my website has no versions in any language except for default English.
How do I solve this?

It's not a great error description, but my suspicion is that the page it is looking at is www.asiapower.org/index.html but the alternate hreflang on that page is set to www.asiapower.org (no index.html).  A self-referencing hreflang should be the exact same URL.
If you don't have other language versions of your site, I'd get rid of the hreflang tag altogether, as it serves no purpose.   Otherwise, having a single URL for your homepage would also work.
As you have a correct canonical tag, this is probably one of those things that's only an issue in Semrush but Google won't actually notice.
